# netty secure websockets using http.. possible?

Tags: javascript, websocket, netty

I have configured my websocket connection following the example:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/sslserver

This all works, i have the browser connecting to a secured websocket using https address.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            var location = "wss://localhost:9999/websocket"

            ws = new WebSocket(location);
            ws.onopen = function(event) { 

            }           
            ws.onclose = function(event) { 

            }

            ws.onmessage = function(event) { 


            }
        });
```

I want to connect to this page that makes the websocket connection using http?... is that possible ?... I have tried this, and it doesn't seem to work.. so im not sure...

I have read that it is possible to create a WSS connection when regardless of going to the page using http or https?.. is this correct?

Comment: If only there was a way to test this on your own...

Comment: @SeanBright - meaning what exactly?.. i have tested it, thats not my question.. its whether its possible... in case im missing something!!.